# Fatest way to check and create folder in document library within SharePoint Online (CSOM)?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, csom

I have a SharePoint Online where I can connect through my console application successfully:

```
private static ClientContext GetUserContext()
{
   var o365SecurePassword = new SecureString();

   foreach (char c in o365Password)
   {
       o365SecurePassword.AppendChar(c);
   }

   var o365Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(o365Username, o365SecurePassword);

   var o365Context = new ClientContext(o365SiteUrl);
   o365Context.Credentials = o365Credentials;

   return o365Context;
}
```

But what I need now to do is to go into my SharePoint Document Library named "doc_archive" and check if there exists a folder with name "K20170409-01". 
If not create a new one.

**Failed Attempt**

```
ClientContext context = GetUserContext();

Web web = context.Web;
Web webroot = context.Site.RootWeb;
context.Load(web);
context.Load(webroot);

List list = webroot.GetList("doc_archive");
context.Load(list);

FolderCollection folders = list.RootFolder.Folders;
context.Load(folders);

IEnumerable<Folder> existingFolders = context.LoadQuery(
    folders.Include(
    folder => folder.Name)
);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

What is the fastest ways to check and create a folder within a document library in SharePoint Online via CSOM (commandline application)?

Comment: What happens exactly on the failed attempt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are happy with using external libraries then the [OfficeDevPnP.Core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core) has some great CSOM extensions for SharePoint and SharePoint Online. It's readily available as a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/) package to add to your projects.

For your requirment there is the [EnsureFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_sites_core/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filefolderextensions.35b06e1c) extension. This function will check if a folder exists, create it if needed and return the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder` object.

Very easy to use:

```
var webRelativeUrlToFolder = "/doc_archive/K20170409-01"
var folder = cc.Web.EnsureFolderPath(webRelativeUrlToFolder);
cc.Load(folder);
cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for how *fast* this would be, but it works in the end on 0365. Note that it throws a `ServerException` if the target already exists.

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{

     ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePwd);

     var list = new ListCreationInformation()
     {
         Title = title
         Description = "User Created Document Library",
         TemplateType = asDocumentLibrary ? 101 : 100 // 100 is a custom list.
     };

    ctx.Web.Lists.Add(list);

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    success = true;
}
```

---

Most CSOM examples are found in Powershell. The process in C# CSOM is actually the same, so next time find a Powershell example when a C# one is not available.